# NetBeans IDE - Problems with PHP hints

Tags: php, netbeans

I just installed NetBeans IDE 7.4 on my PC, because I heard that it's nice for code writing. Then I set up a new project from existing source files and when it opened NetBeans showed hints on places where it should not. For example:

```
$Data = Database::Map("lang/string");
if($Data["lang"] != "") return true;
return false;
```

And NetBeans hints me that `If-Else statements must use braces`. Well, as I know braces aren't required if after the if there is only one line code to run. Another example:

```
public static function checkUrl(){
```

NetBeans says that `Method length is 12(10 allowed)`. I don't even know what this error is about.

Comment: The IDE may be giving code hints for a different language? But additionally for the sake of anyone who ever has to look at your code... ALWAYS USE BRACES FOR IF STATEMENTS.

Comment: Don't let the IDE fool you. I use Aptana Studio 3 and it has no clue what have the modern syntax is. Using arrays like $array = ['test'=>'me']; makes it really mad. If it works on the engine, let the IDE bite you

Comment: 7.4.1 has a lot of issues, the last version I've used that is worth using is 7.3

Comment: I wish could Up arrow @Leeish comment about 20 times

Comment: You can turn the code help off with NetBeans I think. Welcome to NotePad++

Comment: @Leeish I think if the code hints were for different language there would be way more hints and probably errors. PS: I have used Notepad++ and I think it's good, but it has no functionality for object-oriented languages.

Comment: Maybe, but many languages are very similar in many ways. Either way, I don't use NetBeans so I'd listen to @Jessica.

Comment: @Jessica Thanks, I will reinstall

Comment: @Rottingham Thanks, I will check Aptana Studio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These hints are configurable, see Tools -> Options -> Editor -> Hints

[image]

You can adjust it to your needs or disable them. They are only to suggest using best practices and prevent writing bad code